# autodesk-forge Photoscene progress API - Photoscene never progresses

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-realitycapture

I am using the autodesk Forge API calls:

```
// this call starts processing the xdDFs4kdYMGtjo2B7SA8R7PPVKsFK2tOo3JPRNHMMf0 photoscene

$curl_cmd = 
    "curl -s $FORGE_URL/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/xdDFs4kdYMGtjo2B7SA8R7PPVKsFK2tOo3JPRNHMMf0 " .
    "-X 'POST' " .
    "-H 'Content-Type: application/json' " .
    "-H 'Authorization: Bearer $access_token' "
    ;
$json = shell_exec ( $curl_cmd );
```

... then I make the following call repeatedly:

```
// this call starts processing the xdDFs4kdYMGtjo2B7SA8R7PPVKsFK2tOo3JPRNHMMf0 photoscene
    $curl_cmd = "curl -s $FORGE_URL/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/xdDFs4kdYMGtjo2B7SA8R7PPVKsFK2tOo3JPRNHMMf0/progress " .
        "-H 'Content-Type: application/json' " .
        "-H 'Authorization: Bearer $access_token' "
        ;   
    $json = shell_exec ( $curl_cmd );
```

When I decode the $json return variable it has these values:

> progressmsg="Created" 
>   progress="0"
>   photosceneID="xdDFs4kdYMGtjo2B7SA8R7PPVKsFK2tOo3JPRNHMMf0"

Every time I check the progress, the API reports it is in this state perpetually. It never displays the "processing" state described in the API reference, and the progress % variable remains at 0. But the API also never returns an error.

What causes a Photoscene to stay frozen in this "created" status,  without progressing on to "processing"? How can I make the job start processing"?

Answer (score 0):

This situation might be due to either the number of images is too small, or they are corrupted.

To reproduce, create a scene, upload no image and start processing.
When you trigger the scene processing you should have received something like:
[image]

and if you check the scene status, it will give you the very same neverending "progressmsg="Created" progress="0" :

[image]

I would recommend using the endpoint https://developer.api.autodesk.com/photo-to-3d/v1/photoscene/{{RECENT_PHOTOSCENE}}/properties

to see how many images you have in the scene:

[image]

Comment: I am seeing the same issue, re: "progressmsg="Created" progress="0". @denis-grigor, I called the properties API and see a response similar to yours. It shows the seven images I uploaded and shows the status of "PROCESSING", but the process api is still stuck on "Created"

Comment: Ah, looking at your hitchhikers guide article (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/hitchhikers-guide-reality-capture-api), I'm betting I don't have enough photos and they're not good enough. Will look into improving them!

Comment: @denis-grigor do you have a link to their documentation? I've reached out to their support because the link they have on their site is broken but on one has responded.